# User is not authorized to perform: rekognition:RecognizeCelebrities with an explicit deny

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition

When I run a boto3 api (python)file, it always throws an exception error like:
(Amazon-Rekognition)

> User: arn:aws:sts::963971995244:assumed-role/vocstartsoft/user937366=*********** is not authorized to perform: rekognition:RecognizeCelebrities with an explicit deny

Comment: check your iam user permissions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error "explicit deny" means that some policy is blocking this access, like this:

```
"Sid": "example",
"Effect": "Deny",
"Action": "*"
"Resource": "*"
```

Even if there are other policies authorizing the use of rekognition, this deny will overwrite everything, explicitly denying access according to the error.